# 2000 Buick V6 want to remove the air conditioner

Tags: ac, buick

I want to remove the exterior air conditioner parts from the motor because it’s in a convertible (compressor/radiator/hoses). Do I need seal the hose or anything else to worry with ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To help me better understand, you don't use the AC so you want to remove all of the parts involved? Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, mainly want to remove the full size coolant radiator (don’t think that what it’s called) which sets in front of the actual radiator, which is hurting the cooling of the engine in traffic and hot days.

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to remove all of the parts, the first thing you need to do is to get the system evacuated. If there is R134a still remaining in the system, it is against the law (here in the States) to dump refrigerant to atmosphere.

After that, just remove the parts you want to take off. If you want to take the compressor off, realize you'll need to get an idler pulley to replace it, because without it in place, the belt routing won't work. A better option is to just leave it in place. It should not be in the way and won't be creating any heat issues for your engine. Removing the rest is pretty much just unbolting things. If you have no inclination of ever getting it to work again, don't worry about plugging holes or tubes as it will not matter. You may need to take the front end apart to get the condenser (the radiator looking thing ahead of your actual radiator) out. It is usually placed in front of the radiator but mounted to the core support. The lines are fairly simple, too ... just remove everything back to where they connect at the firewall behind the engine. You'll want to leave the bits and pieces which are inside the cabin in place, as they help direct the air flow.

On a separate note, you state these parts are hurting the cooling of the engine when in traffic and on hot days. I'd suggest to you the AC components really don't have anything to do with restricting the cooling, even though you don't use it. If the engine is overheating, you've got other issues going on. The system is designed to allow air go pass through the fins of the condenser whether you're using the AC or not. This could indicate a problem with the thermostat, a plugged radiator, or a weak radiator hose.